# Exception when Removing Items on wp8 longlistselector

Tags: windows-phone-8, longlistselector

I’m having an issue with removing items with the WP8 `LongListSelector` control.

I bind `ItemsSource` with `ObservableCollection` and I have 5 items on the list.

If I call remove Item ( `Items.RemoveAt(0)`) 3 times, It's OK. But when there are 2 items left in the list, It will thrown Exception:

```
System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
```

If there are 10 items in the list, it seems to be thrown when there are 4 items left, etc.

How I can resolve this Issue?

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please provide a piece of your code?

Comment: The behaviour you've described doesn't happen if you're just adding or removing items from an ObservableCollection<T>. There must be more going on than you've described. Can you show a way to recreate this behaviour?

Comment: I have 2 button: "Add Item" and "Remove Item" button.
When click on Add Item, I call 'Items.Add(Item)'. try tapping "Add Item" 5 times and then "Remove Item" 5 times. When there are 2 items left in the list, tapping "Remove Item" will crash the app. It happen when I remove from Top to Bottom. But not happen when remove from Bottom to top